# Applying a "static" filter while paging across the RStudio Source Editor GUI

Tags: r, user-interface, rstudio

When transforming from pivot longer to pivot wider many columns are created during intermediary steps, while debugging. for me it is easier to use the GUI, while i transform the data when checking for errors because in many instances it does not fit into the R console. Therefore, I would like to filter a column in the GUI and have the row or filter remain static, while using the "Cols: >> button".

Because i am a new user i cannot paste the R GUI Editor window to show the steps visually, however, i will write them in chronological order.
1.
Filter a column by ID "134"
2.
use navigation GUI button Cols: ">>" to page right for more than 50 columns in the data set.
3.
arrive at column 100 with filter applied. Displaying the subject filtered by ID "134".

This seems basic but i couldn't find a post about it. thnx

Comment: But you can filter the Id and then view it. `df %>% filter(ID == 134) %>% View`

Comment: @RonakShah there are more than 50 columns, which are interrelated (one column uses the other) so i would need to use the "select" column, however, it is easier to just use the GUI when debugging because i have several dependencies.